Why does \input\contents not work, \input\jobname.toc does ? Self constructed tableofcontents
This is the code
%pdfTeX

\newcount\sections
\sections=0
\newcount\subsections
\subsections=0
\newcount\subsubsections
\subsubsections=0
\newwrite\contents
\immediate\openout\contents=\jobname.toc
%
%Here is the question uncomment
\def\tableofcontents#1{\vskip2\baselineskip#1}%dummy
%\def\tableofcontents#1{\vskip2\baselineskip{\bf #1} \vskip\baselineskip\immediate\closeout\contents \input\contents}%first. uncomment  
%\def\tableofcontents#1{\vskip2\baselineskip{\bf #1} \vskip\baselineskip\immediate\closeout\contents \input\jobname.toc}%second ,uncomment  
%Here is the question
%
\def\section#1{\vskip\baselineskip\advance\sections by 1  \immediate\write\contents{\the\sections\hskip2pt   #1 \hfill\the\pageno\vskip\baselineskip}\vskip\baselineskip{\bf \the\sections\hskip1em #1 }\subsections=0 \vskip\baselineskip}
\def\subsection#1{\vskip\baselineskip\advance\subsections by 1  \immediate\write\contents{\the\sections.\the\subsections \hskip2pt  #1\hfill\the\pageno\vskip\baselineskip}{\bf \the\sections.\the\subsections\hskip1em #1} \subsubsections=0\vskip\baselineskip}
\def\subsubsection#1{\vskip\baselineskip\advance\subsubsections by 1  \immediate\write\contents{\the\sections.\the\subsections.\the\subsubsections \hskip2pt  #1\hfill\the\pageno\vskip\baselineskip}{\bf \the\sections.\the\subsections.\the\subsubsections\hskip1em #1}\vskip\baselineskip}
\section{Section}
Some text. 
\subsection{Subsection}
Some text. 
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Some text. 
\subsection{Subsection}
Some text. 
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Some text. 
Some text. 
\tableofcontents{Contents}
\bye


Note that you are not using (just) core TeX. Your code also depends at least on the macros defined in the plain format.
When you read or write a file, you actually read or write to an input or output stream which you've attached1 to that file. TeX has 16 input and output streams available.
\immediate\openout\contents=\jobname.toc

This tells TeX to allocate an available output stream, which is designated by a number, to the file \jobname.toc and to set \contents to the number of the allocated stream.
\contents is just a pointer to the name of the allocated stream. It is the stream which is actually hooked up to the file \jobname.toc.
If you want to read back in the same way i.e. using a stream directly, you need to use \read rather than \input and to allocate an input stream in the same way you allocate an output stream. For example,
\newread\readcontents

sets \readcontents to point to the number of an input stream in the same way that \contents points to the number of an output stream.
Jumping ahead, an extra boolean will be handy.
\newif\ifmore

Then after you close the output stream, you can allocate the input stream to the file you've just finished with.
  \openin\readcontents=\jobname.toc

\read reads the file one line at a time, so we iterate over the lines, reading one at a time and outputting the contents until we get to the end of the file. We can use plain's loop to do this
  \loop
    \read\readcontents to \cscontents

Now we have the first line of the toc in \cscontents, so lets add it to the output stream for typesetting.
    \cscontents

Check for end-of-file,
    \ifeof\readcontents
      \morefalse
    \else
      \moretrue
    \fi

If we've not reached the end, repeat the loop.
    \ifmore
    \repeat

Tidy up by closing the input stream.
  \closein\readcontents

Complete code:
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729357/
% addaswyd o gwestwin MBE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/729337/
\newcount\sections
\sections=0
\newcount\subsections
\subsections=0
\newcount\subsubsections
\subsubsections=0
\newwrite\contents
\immediate\openout\contents=\jobname.toc
\newread\readcontents
\newif\ifmore
\def\tableofcontents#1{%
  \vskip2\baselineskip{\bf #1} \vskip\baselineskip\immediate\closeout\contents
  \openin\readcontents=\jobname.toc
  \loop
    \read\readcontents to \cscontents
    \cscontents
    \ifeof\readcontents
      \morefalse
    \else
      \moretrue
    \fi
    \ifmore
    \repeat
  \closein\readcontents
}%first. uncomment
\def\section#1{\vskip\baselineskip\advance\sections by 1  \immediate\write\contents{\the\sections\hskip2pt   #1 \hfill\the\pageno\vskip\baselineskip}\vskip\baselineskip{\bf \the\sections\hskip1em #1 }\subsections=0 \vskip\baselineskip}
\def\subsection#1{\vskip\baselineskip\advance\subsections by 1  \immediate\write\contents{\the\sections.\the\subsections \hskip2pt  #1\hfill\the\pageno\vskip\baselineskip}{\bf \the\sections.\the\subsections\hskip1em #1} \subsubsections=0\vskip\baselineskip}
\def\subsubsection#1{\vskip\baselineskip\advance\subsubsections by 1  \immediate\write\contents{\the\sections.\the\subsections.\the\subsubsections \hskip2pt  #1\hfill\the\pageno\vskip\baselineskip}{\bf \the\sections.\the\subsections.\the\subsubsections\hskip1em #1}\vskip\baselineskip}
\section{Section}
Some text.
\subsection{Subsection}
Some text.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Some text.
\subsection{Subsection}
Some text.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Some text.
Some text.
\tableofcontents{Contents}
\bye

1Surely the wrong term. Note that I do not know the correct terminology! Something like assigning a file descriptor, possibly?

[will doubtless delete sooner rather than later ... ]

Thank s for the fine answers.

If you do \show\contents, you see
> \contents=\char"0.

The command \contents is just an internal handle (which happens to be a number as it's defined with \chardef) and does not refer in any way to the file name.
On the other hand
\input\jobname.toc

is exactly what you need. To be on the safer side
\input\jobname.toc\relax

Some more details. TeX has sixteen write streams and sixteen read streams; these are completely independent from the input mechanism.
A write stream can be open or not. If it is open, to its number is associated a file. However, keeping track of numbers is complicated, so plain TeX has the allocation feature \newwrite, which creates a command to stand for the next free stream: what TeX does when you do \newwrite\contents is to look at the last allocated write stream and to do
\chardef\contents=<last stream number + 1>

In the particular case the number is zero because it's the first allocation, but you aren't required to know.
The connection with a file name is done with \openout.
Why doesn't \contents refer to the file name? There are several reasons, but the main one is that when you close the stream, the connection is forgotten. And you can reuse the same output stream for different purposes: say that you want to save a notes for each chapter.
You do \newwrite\notes and, at the beginning of the chapter you do
\immediate\closeout\notes
\immediate\openout\notes=\jobname-\chapternumber.nts

At the end of the document you do \immediate\closeout\notes in order to close the last one and now you can input all the notes chapter by chapter. Why doing this way and not with a “global” notes file? Because you plan to possibly print the notes at the end of each chapter and the modification would be easy to do.
Now you know one reason why \notes cannot refer to a specific file name: what file should \notes refer to?
There are other reasons: \write and \input are completely different methods to access files. With \openout TeX agrees with the OS to open a file where to write a line each time a \write instruction is performed; how this is done depends on specific features of the OS. With \input TeX asks the OS to be fed with the contents of a complete file.

So," \immediate\write\contents{xy}" knows, which file is meant, but " \input\contents" does not?

@MBE I added some more details on how the mechanism works.
